# PathPredicateEvaluator search for two paths

Tags: java, aem

I have a really complex query using HashMap and the QueryBuilder, part of it has something like this:

```
    map.put("path", "/content");
    map.put("path.exact", "true"); // defaults to true
    map.put("path.flat", "true");
    map.put("path.self", "true");
```

I took that code from this [page](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/search/querybuilder/impl/SampleQueryBuilder.java)

this works as intended but I need my query to search for content in two possible paths, so it would be to search in two paths with an "OR" relationship. I haven't found any documentation on how to do that, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use groups:

```
map.put("group.1_path", "/content/path1");
map.put("group.2_path", "/content/path2");
map.put("group.p.or", "true");
```

[Documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html#Searchundermultiplepathsusinggroups)